# How to get the max date from Joined tables in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have four tables that I am joining to get some data I need. The tables and some sample data are as follows:

```
**TollTransaction table**       
AccountId   EntryTransDt    LicPlateNo
1655024     24-05-2017          ABC123
1655024     24-05-2017          DEF123
1655024     24-05-2017          GHI123
1655024     24-05-2017          JKL123
1655024     24-05-2017          MNO123


**Plate table**     
AccountId   LicPlateNo  EndDate
11001       ABC123      2012-06-10
1898884     ABC123      NULL
1981834     DEF123      NULL
14066       GHI123      NULL
1770746     JKL123      NULL
1005010     MNO123      NULL


**Account table**       
AccountId   AccountNumber   CurrentBalance
11001       10110014        0
14066       10140668        0
1005010     20050108        0
1770746     27707463        3.9
1898884     28988847        0
1981834     29818345        0


**FinTransMaster table**        
FinTransTypeCode    BusinessDay AcctID
PYMT                03-02-2015  11001
PYMT                15-01-2015  11001
PYMT                11-12-2014  14066
PYMT                11-09-2014  14066
PYMT                01-04-2016  1005010
PYMT                02-10-2014  1005010
PYMT                15-09-2015  1770746
PYMT                30-11-2015  1898884
PYMT                21-10-2015  1898884
PYMT                23-03-2017  1981834
```

The AccountId in TollTransaction table is the same for those Licence plates because those licence plates follow a common criteria.

I need to get AccountIds from the Plate table and then join the Account table on AccountIds to get the AccountNumber.

**What I'm trying to do:**

1. I'm trying to find Accounts that have a Current Balance in payment.
2. The last date the payment was made (max BusinessDay from FinTransMaster table).
3. The last EntryTransDt in TollTransaction table for that LicPlateNo.

**My code is as follows:**

```
    SELECT A.AccountNumber
          ,A.CurrentBalance
          ,MAX(F.BusinessDay) over(Partition by F.AcctID) as Last_Pymt_date
          ,MAX(T.EntryTransDt) over(Partition by T.LicPlateNo) as Last_Transaction
    FROM TollTransaction T
    INNER JOIN Plate P ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
    INNER JOIN Account A ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
    LEFT JOIN FinTransMaster F ON A.AccountId = F.AcctID

    WHERE T.AccountId = '1655024'
      AND P.EndDate IS NULL
      AND A.CurrentBalance > 0
      AND F.FinTransTypeCode = 'PYMT'

    ORDER BY Last_Pymt_Date DESC, A.AccountNumber
```

But I got way too many records.

My TollTransactions table has multiple records for the same LicPlateNo. That is why I'm getting multiple records after the JOINs. If I could JOIN only Distinct T.LicPlateNo to the other tables, I should get single records.

**EDIT:** 
I used @SQLZim code provided below but I still get some duplicates. See part of results below:

```
AccountNumber   CurrentBalance  Last_Pymt_date  Last_Transaction
1004219         40.33           24-05-2017      23-05-2017
1004219         40.33           24-05-2017      21-05-2017
1004219         40.33           24-05-2017      19-05-2017
1004219         40.33           24-05-2017      26-05-2016
1082215         60.01           24-05-2017      27-03-2017
1043516         181.25          24-05-2017      07-03-2016
1043516         181.25          24-05-2017      24-05-2017
1043516         181.25          24-05-2017      20-05-2017
1043516         181.25          24-05-2017      03-10-2015
```

I even commented out T.LastTRansaction in two places, to remove that field. I still get duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard aggregation query with `group by` instead of using window functions for aggregation:

```
select  A.AccountNumber
      , A.CurrentBalance
      , max(F.BusinessDay) as Last_Pymt_date
      , max(T.EntryTransDt) as Last_Transaction
from Account A  
  inner join Plate P 
    on P.AccountId = A.AccountId
  inner join tollTransaction T 
    on T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
  left join FinTransMaster F 
    on A.AccountId = F.Acctid
where A.AccountId = '1655024'
  and A.CurrentBalance > 0
  and P.EndDate is null
  and F.FinTransTypeCode = 'pymt'
group by  
    A.AccountNumber
  , A.CurrentBalance
```

Comment: Thank you SqlZim but I'm getting duplicate records. Please can you see my edit in my question?

Comment: INNER JOINing Plate with TollTransaction will give multiple records because TollTransaction table has multiple records for the same LicPlateNo. I need to join only Distinct LicPlateNo from TollTransaction with Plate table.

Comment: @user1777929 I don't think you need `LicPlateNo` at all. Answer updated.